# No output in Eclipse console, though rest of method works

Tags: java, system.out

I am getting nothing out in my console from my `System.out.println()` in the following code:

```
    LinkedList<Element> ls = count(list);
    File outFile = new File(args[1]);
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(outFile);
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    for(int i = 0; i < ls.size(); i++) {
        bw.write((int) ls.get(i).data);
        System.out.println("Written out " + ls.get(i).data);
    }
    bw.flush();
    bw.close();
```

`Element` object is only a class with an `int key;` and an `Object data;` 
The `BufferedWriter` is writing out to the file as it should, but my Console in Eclipse doesn't get the `System.out.println();` calls. When I run it in debug mode with breakpoint at `bw.write()` I keep pressing F8 (hotkey to resume), until the `BufferedWriter` is done, but nothing gets into the Console. Any ideas of why?

Comment: What's `ls`? It isn't declared in your code.

Comment: In Window > Preferences > Run/Debug > Console, is the "Show when program writes to standard out" checkbox checked?

Comment: ls works right in the line just above (bw.write), but somehow, System.out.println can't reach the same Object a few nanoseconds later (nothing modified by bw.write)

Comment: Yes, Eclipse is set to show whe program writes to standard output (works in other lines, executed earlier in same program, still using system.out.println function)

Comment: Looks like your 'ls` already equals `0`

Comment: data and list cannot be resolved if I compile that as a main().

Comment: Check if the outFile is empty. If so, the 'ls' is empty, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, please don't use the System console for your logging. Second, add a call to `flush()`. Finally, make sure you add the same cast you used before (or just save it to a variable).

```
int payload = (int) ls.get(i).data;
bw.write(payload);
System.out.println("Written out " + payload);
// Or,
// System.out.println("Written out " + ((int) ls.get(i).data));
System.out.flush();
```

Comment: Didn't fix it, I am still getting nothing into the console.

Comment: @Zuenonentu Edited. Make sure you cast it the same as for your write.

Comment: That did the trick. I added the typecast back to an int as you told me to, and now it works. I'll try use Logger instead, though it writes out in console too

Comment: Logger writes in console because the default appender, but you can write it wherever you need. Take a look at Log4J library, for example. It's easy to use and understand.

Comment: So was it the SOP flush that did the trick or doing the cast outside the bw.write method ? Just wanted to know the reason why it started working again ?

Comment: @AbdullahShaikh Needed the cast to an int. My assumption is the the data content was non-printable.

Comment: Was the cast as @ElliottFrisch said.

Answer (score 0):

Try outputting the variables for the for loop such as the ls.size(), if nothing is being output there then your code isn't being called at all but if it is then you should be able to figure out what is wrong.

since we don't know what is in ls we don't know if it may even be empty

so to help us try putting

```
System.out.println("List: " + ls);
System.out.println("List size: " + ls.size());
```

just before the for loop and tell us the outputs.

Comment: I added what you told me to, and I get nothing (even added .flush). Here's the epic thing though: If I use System.err.println instead of .out, then I get all the lines which should be printed. That's all I edited (from .out to .err). Strange, but it's solved

Comment: So the code was running but there was just something wrong with the System.out displaying? I've never seen that before, well at least your problem is solved :D

Comment: There's a first time for every thing. But yes my code was running, because if I went in and deleted the written file (from bw.write() method), it would be generated again after I run the program, and I used the debug tool inside Eclipse to see if the code was running at all.